# Spring boot - bad TCP connection handling

Tags: java, http, spring-boot, tcp

We're using a REST web application written in Spring Boot & Java.
After some time of system usage and checking the open ports to the server, it seems like we have a leak in handling the connections

> Netstat -nao | grep 4567

This return the attached output even when no browser is open and no connection is actively made to the server
I'd be glad for any assistance on this because it seems that Spring is mishandling the connections or it might be a mis-configuration on our side.

- TCP    172.17.1.80:4567       172.18.11.36:54208     TIME_WAIT       0
- (Many more such entries to different internal ports)
- TCP    172.17.1.80:4567       172.18.11.36:54209     CLOSE_WAIT      4756
- (Many more such entries to different internal ports)
- TCP    172.17.1.80:4567       172.18.11.36:54542     CLOSE_WAIT      4756

Comment: Nothing wrong with the TIME_WAIT entries, but the CLOSE_WAIT ones are a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The issue's been the fact the HttpResponse hasn't been closed, to fix this I've used HttpClientUtils.closeQuietly, see below :

```
HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.execute(createHttpRequest(url, timeOut));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
        }
        return result;
    } catch (org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException e) {
        throw new HostUnreachableException(e);
    } finally {
        HttpClientUtils.closeQuietly(response);
    }
```